# How to make the code shorter with keeping loop?

Tags: javascript

How to make the code shorter with keeping loop?

```
    var age = prompt("What is your age");

    for (var i=18; i<=age ; i++){
        alert ("Welcome");

    break
    }

    for (var i=18; i>age ; i++){
        alert ("Sorry, You are Under 18");
    break

    }
```

Comment: why looping if else should do the job

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in/

Answer (score 2):

An awful lot of your example code seems wrong.  You are using loops where you should be using conditionals and  your loop conditions would be likely to not trigger until numeric overflow, except you unconditionally break from the loops anyway (which further suggests that you want to be using conditionals, not a loop).

What you probably want is this:

```
if( age >= 18) {
  alert("Welcome");
} else {
  alert("Sorry, you are under 18");
}
```

Comment: @user135992 - there is no reason to use a loop, you don't want to use a loop, you shouldn't use a loop ;-).